# Table relationship design in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am a little bit confused with my table relationships. I wish some one could help clarify, and tell me where I am going wrong.

I have three tables: one stores students basic info (students_info), the other stores their classes (students_class) and the last stores their positions (students_positions).

students_info

| st_id | f_name | l_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | quinoo | mickel |
| 2 | nunoo | gyan |
| 3 | kwanis | nnipa |

students_class

| cl_id | class | academic_year | st_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | A | 2013 | 2 |
| 32 | B | 2014 | 1 |
| 73 | C | 2014 | 3 |

students_positions

| pos_id | positions | ushered_year | st_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | President | 2013 | 2 |
| 34 | secretary | 2014 | 3 |

This is what I have done so far. But I friend saw my tables and its relationships and he was like, it would be best i create another table to contain all the ids column values in addition to the table I have, this wat he suggested

students

| all_std | st_id | cl_id | pos_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 32 | null |
| 02 | 2 | 13 | 54 |
| 03 | 3 | 73 | 34 |

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what's the point of the table your friend suggested.

The only improvement I suggest is to add a `classes` table :

| cl_id | class | academic_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | A | 2013 |
| 32 | B | 2014 |
| 73 | C | 2014 |

And then students_class would only link between the student and the class :

| cl_id | st_id |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 32 | 1 |
| 73 | 3 |

This way the properties of each class will be stored once in the classes table instead of being duplicated in the students_class table for students that share the same class.